# ADF Lookup Activity Row Limitation

Tags: azure-data-factory

We have to fetch records 10k+ records from source by using ADF Lookup activities but there is limitation for Lookup activity is only allow 5000 records at a time to fetch from source system. in this case how do we handle the solution in azure data factory. what is the best approach to complete this solution.

we have to use existing system generate the business logic select query to apply in lookup. kindly help me to give your guidelines.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please state what you are trying to achieve post the look up activity? And what is the source on which you are executing your lookup query

Comment: source oracle db to connect and fetch the data in lookup activity, post lookup activity we have to store the data into ADLS and mssql db. in lookup activity we have to execute select operation for multiple table join and fech the records

Answer (score 0):

> source oracle db to connect and fetch the data in lookup activity, post lookup activity we have to store the data into ADLS and mssql db

If your requirement is to get the data in ADLS, then **you can directly use copy activity to copy the data from Oracle DB to ADLS Gen2** without using lookup activity.

If you want to get the JSON array only using lookup activity, then the below workaround might work for you. This approach requires adding a new column to the table which should have incremented number starting from 1. You can use [`ROWNUM`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/pseudocolumns008.htm) for that.

After creating a new column to the table, use Until activity in ADF. Inside Until activity, use a counter(start value of this should be `5000`) and increment it by `5000` in every iteration. The end condition for the Until is the counter should not be greater than the total table count.

So, in every iteration, use lookup activity. Use CTE expression [`WITH`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-8.0-en/with.html) for the below query and do your joins on that in the lookup query.

```
select * from example_table where inc_column>@{add(variables('counter'),-5000)} and inc_column<=@{variables('counter')}
```

This will select the 5000 rows in every iteration.

After this, use `union()` function inside ForEach. This will union the lookup array in every iteration with previous iteration lookup arrays and the result of the union after the ForEach will give JSON array of all rows from the table.

**Go through below sample demo:**

Here, for sample I am taking the threshold value `5` instead of `5000` and my table count is `20`.

First create the following variables in your pipeline.

[image]

In the first set variable activity, set the `counter` variable to lookup limit which is `5000`. In next set variable activity, store the table row count in `tablecount` variable.

In Until activity, give the expression like below.

```
@greater(variables('counter'), variables('tablecount'))
```

[image]

Inside until activity, take lookup activity and you need to build your query in lookup using `CTE` for the above query and your joins.

[image]

Then take a set variable activity and assign variable `res_json_arr` to `temp_lookup_arr`. After that, use the below expression in another set variable activity and store it in `res_json_arr` variable.

```
@union(variables('temp_lookup_arr'),activity('Lookup1').output.value)
```

Now, you need to increment the `counter` variable by threshold value. For that take a set variable activity for the variable `temp` and give the below expression.

```
@add(variables('counter'), 5000)
```

[image]

Then, in the last set variable activity, reassign the `temp` variable back to the `counter` variable.

Debug the pipeline and it will union every lookup JSON array and the result JSON array will be like this.

[image]

**This is my pipeline JSON**, change the threshold value from `5` to `5000` in all expressions.

```
{
    "name": "pipeline1",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "table count",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "set counter to lookup limit",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "tablecount",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@int('20')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Until1",
                "type": "Until",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "table count",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "expression": {
                        "value": "@greater(variables('counter'), variables('tablecount'))",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Lookup1",
                            "type": "Lookup",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "source": {
                                    "type": "AzureSqlSource",
                                    "sqlReaderQuery": {
                                        "value": "select * from example_table where inc_column>@{add(variables('counter'),-5)} and inc_column<=@{variables('counter')}",
                                        "type": "Expression"
                                    },
                                    "queryTimeout": "02:00:00",
                                    "partitionOption": "None"
                                },
                                "dataset": {
                                    "referenceName": "AzureSqlTable1",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                                },
                                "firstRowOnly": false
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "update temp with counter add lookup limit",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Union lookup output and temp_lookup_arr",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "temp",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@add(variables('counter'), 5)",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Update counter with temp",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "update temp with counter add lookup limit",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "counter",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@variables('temp')",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "res_json_arr to temp_lookup_arr",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Lookup1",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "temp_lookup_arr",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@variables('res_json_arr')",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Union lookup output and temp_lookup_arr",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "res_json_arr to temp_lookup_arr",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "res_json_arr",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@union(variables('temp_lookup_arr'),activity('Lookup1').output.value)",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "set counter to lookup limit",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "counter",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@int('5')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "tablecount": {
                "type": "Integer"
            },
            "counter": {
                "type": "Integer"
            },
            "temp_lookup_arr": {
                "type": "Array"
            },
            "temp": {
                "type": "Integer"
            },
            "res_json_arr": {
                "type": "Array"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```